Passing an Action to a Custom Control through Bindable Property in .NET MAUI
The main idea:
I want to pass an Action from a ViewModel to a CustomControl, such that whenever these Actions are invoked from the ViewModel, it automatically invokes a method within the CustomControl.
The detailed idea:
I want to be able to show some messages on command. So I have these Actions on my MainViewModel that are invoked whenever I need them to show.
public class MainViewModel
{
    // assuming these get and set methods are basically normal gets and sets
    public Action ShowErrorMsg
    {
        get => GetValue<Action>();
        set => SetValue(value);
    }

    public Action ShowSuccessMsg
    {
        get => GetValue<Action>();
        set => SetValue(value);
    }

    public void SendMessage()
    {
        // some send message logic here
        // ...

        // invoke the actions based on result
        if (sendSuccess)
        {
            ShowSuccessMsg?.Invoke();
        }
        else ShowErrorMsg?.Invoke();
    }
}

I have a CustomLabel control class that extends from Label, and it sits in the MainView.xaml like this, and I want it to pass in said Actions:
<controls:CustomLabel Text="Error!" TextColor="Red"
                      ShowMessageAction="{Binding ShowErrorMsg}" />

<controls:CustomLabel Text="Success!" TextColor="Green"
                      ShowMessageAction="{Binding ShowSuccessMsg}" />


In the CustomLabel class, a BindableProperty will be assigned with any arbitrary Action and I want it to be invoked whenever the Action in MainViewModel is invoked. From there, an animation is fired, and the text fades out in 8 seconds.
public class CustomLabel : Label
{ 
    public static readonly BindableProperty ShowMessageActionProperty =
       BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ShowMessageAction), 
                               typeof(Action), 
                               typeof(CustomLabel), 
                               propertyChanged: OnShowMessageChanged);

    public Action ShowMessageAction
    {
        get => (Action)GetValue(ShowMessageActionProperty);
        set => SetValue(ShowMessageActionProperty, value);
    }
    
    // this should be fired when there is a new Action binded
    public static void OnShowMessageChanged(BindableObject sender, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var thisLabel = sender as CustomLabel;

        var action = newValue as Action;
       
        // subscribe the animation method to the Action that this class is bound to
        action += thisLabel.ShowMessageAnimation;
    }

    // animation is fired when action is called, fades out in 8 seconds
    private void ShowMessageAnimation()
    {
        this.IsVisible = true;

        Timer timer = new Timer(8000);
        timer.Elapsed += (_, _) =>
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Dispatch(async () =>
            {
                await this.FadeTo(0, 1000);
                this.IsVisible = false;
                this.Opacity = 1;
            });
        };

        timer.Start();
    }
}

However, unless I explicitly specify the Action from within CustomLabel, the Action from MainViewModel and ShowMessageAction don't sync as it should (sometimes the propertyChanged isn't even fired at all). Is there a fundamental gap in my knowledge, or is there a workaround/ a better way to approach this that I am completely missing?
What I have tried:

I have tried assigning ShowMessageAction with MainViewModel.ShowMessage in the constructor and that works fine, but does not allow me to be flexible on which Action I want to pass in.
I have tried subscribing within the Set method in ShowMessageAction property, manually subscribing from MainView.xaml.cs, to no avail.


You are breaking MVVM by doing this instead you should have a property (may be a boolean TLDR) that changes and triggers this!

@FreakyAli A boolean isn't what I really want since the animation fades away in 10 seconds, so I would have to manually turn it to true and then false from the control, which sounds kinda janky to me. Can you explain to me how I am breaking MVVM? I am trying to learn the limits of what I can and cannot do.

A core principle of the MVVM architecture is that your ViewModel or View should not be aware of each others state i.e. agnostic to each other by doing this what you would do is make your View aware of a method in the VM that basically guides it to make changes to the View, the bool part was just an example you could do whatever suits you, generally in MVVM scenarios animations are never driven by the VM, you do it in the View code behind

@FreakyAli I'm not sure I follow, if I do end up using a boolean in my ViewModel and bind it with my control wouldn't it be essentially the same as using an Action? How would I trigger animations if I can't bind these triggers to the VM (if I am sending an email in the VM, I want a bool property called "Sending" and the view would have an ActivityIndicator visible in the xaml/ code behind for example). The animation is not running on the ViewModel, it is running in the code behind.
Would you be able to suggest a better solution to this rather than what I'm doing?

Its not the same, the difference is very subtle but if you were experienced in MVVM you would understand instantly, the basic difference is in one case all you are doing is making your View aware that a property in your ViewModel changed that needs to update something in the View, in the other case you are passing something from the ViewModel to your View and letting your View choose how it should affect something in your ViewModel

To answer your question about showing an indicator you can choose to show it through your ViewModel at the end of the day you maintain your code but generally when you see good codebases they main an IsBusy flag in their ViewModels which triggers this...

@FreakyAli I understand the fundamental of an MVVM where the ViewModel should not be aware of the View. And that is exactly what I'm doing, I am making my View (the CustomLabel control) aware of the change of a property in the VM (the ShowMessage action) whenever it is invoked. The ViewModel isn't aware of the CustomLabel, and the CustomLabel is 100% not updating the ViewModel anywhere. In this specific scenario, and based on your vast experience in MVVM, can you again suggest me an actual working solution for what I want to do?

Usually we use mvvm to handle changes in the content of the view, and if you want to handle the method, you can put the logic code into the view backend code.
